# Add data attribute to each li in menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, filters

I have a menu listing all of my products categories in Woocommerce. I need to add an attribute `data-relation` to each `<li>` tag and the value for each one would be the ID of the category.

I success to do it for the `<a>` tag. Does it exist a filter for `<li>`?

Here is the PHP filter function:

```
function category_menu_id_attribute ($atts, $item, $args) {
  $atts['data-relation'] = $item->object_id;
  return $atts;
  }
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'category_menu_id_attribute', 10, 3);
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note that the above code will attach the ID of the `nav_item` post, not the term/product category. Nav menus are a taxonomy, and each item in the menu is a post of type `nav_item`. Why do you need this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there's no such filter yet. You'd need to use a custom walker and override the [`Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/) which builds the `<li>` tag.

Comment: And actually @TomJNowell, `object_id` is the ID of the "object" (post, category, tag, etc.) originally represented by the nav menu item, and the nav menu item ID is stored in `$item->ID` and `$item->db_id`. See [`wp_setup_nav_menu_item()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_setup_nav_menu_item/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TomJNowell, I need it to create a relation between a menu with categories and a list of these categories with thumbnails.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ, I also read about the custom walker. But the tutorials I saw are 10-8 years old so I hoped there was a new filter. Anyway it's fine, I will use the code provided above and create the attribute on the `<a>` tag. Thanks again!

Comment: @MathieuPréaud so you are trying to put thumbnails on menu items? Or icons? You don't need to add a data attribute for that, WP already adds lots of HTML classes you can use to do it entirely with CSS. E.g. a page in a menu will have lots of classes such as `page-item`, `menu-item-type-post_type`, or `page-item-64` ( where 64 is the ID of the page ). Adding a data attribute is unnecessary as the information is already there ( also why didn't you ask how to put thumbnails on menu items? You've fallen into the classic [X Y Problem trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) )